# "Outdoor Mode" on laptop gone, lost ~200 nits of brightness. Workarounds? Galaxy Flex Alpha 2

Tags: windows, laptop, brightness

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Flex Alpha 2 since it was touted to have a 600 nits brightness feature called "Outdoor Mode".

There is a button (FN+F10) dedicated to it, which does nothing. There is also supposed to be a setting for it in the included application "Samsung Settings" which is absent. All proprietary drivers are updated via "Samsung Update."

Doing some research I couldn't find any verifiable information, however one user on Reddit thinks that it was removed in a recent patch via Samsung. https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyBook/comments/pdpmbm/what_happened_to_outdoor_mode_on_my_flex2_alpha/

So, I'm trying to figure out a way to reclaim these lost NITS of brightness, whether it be from hacks, third party software, or jumping down the rabbit hole of old driver versions and software, but I don't know where to start looking on how to solve this problem.

Computer is on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: When you contacted Samsung support with regards to the current availability of Outdoor Mode what was their response?

Comment: @Ramhound ask for a refund from amazon. lmao. I was actually able to resolve this issue on my own, will post an answer now hopefully it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the Samsung Update software, I had all the drivers updated, but hidden in the "Apps" section were some options were "Display Color" and "Color Engine". Updating these allowed me to use the <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> hotkey.